# Select a text and copy to another websites xpath element

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a extension for myself that helps me to select a text and search it in other websites.
For example, i select a text then when i right click with context menu, it says search with preferred site.
But i need to copy the selection, and paste it into the websites search bar with that extension.

I manage to select the text and make the context menu launch. But the main goal is copy selection and paste search into other websites search bar. I tried some xpath but still no success.

Is there any way to succeed it?

Checked online resources about xpath and document.querySelector.

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickedObj){

if(clickedObj.menuItemId == "eksiAra"){
  function copy() {
    var copyText = document.querySelector("#input");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  document.querySelector("#copy").addEventListener("click", copy);

}
```

})

Comment: show us what you have already done, I mean the code.

Comment: i edited the original post.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page with its own dummy DOM which you are accessing now. You need an additional content script and maybe messaging to tie it all together. See the official documentation.